# if Brahman has no attributes like mind,memory.Then how he created universe?

Tags: brahman

if Brahman has no attributes like mind,memory.Then how he created universe?if we say maya created with the presence of brahman. maya is jada.if i want to create some thing i have to use my mind to create. if brahman has no mind how can he create universe. Without mind how brahman can think and use his total capacity called maya. Stula sarira and sukshama saria it is created and it is inside sristi.
to design sukshama saria (mind) he have to think and to design mind and its order.My 
Question is Brahman has no mind no memory no attributes then how can he able to design universe or he can able to create and design without mind?

Comment: (In advaita) Creator of the universe is saguna brahman, who has attributes.

Comment: How do you know the brahman has no attributes?